# Node authors notified by email when a comment is added using trigger module - node token not getting

Tags: emails, tokens, rules

My goal is to send a notification email to the node author when a new comment is added. For this i am using trigger module. But didn't get the node author mail id.

[image: configuration]

Any one experienced in it?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try these module
http://drupal.org/project/comment_notify

Video tutorial
http://drupalize.me/videos/notify-author-comments
http://drupalize.me/videos/notify-comment-reply

Answer (score 4):

I got the token for the question i posted here.

`[node:author:mail]` should be replaced with `[comment:node:author:mail]`

[drupal.org link to refer](http://drupal.org/node/455042#comment-5575602)